# Error to run Configuration Wizard of weblogic 10.3.6 : JVM Launcher is showing 'could not create the java virtual machine' error

Tags: java, weblogic, soa

Error while running 'Configuration Wizard' of weblogic 10.3.6

## error is  java virtual machine launcher error: 'could not create the java virtual machine. A fatal exception has occurred, program will exit'

My JDK-8 location is : C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_25 and the same is referenced while installing Weblogic (64 bit) server.

Note: 
1) "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7" is the default jre that got installed with the Windows8.1 while purchasing the machine.

2) I have not set any system variables to JAVA_HOME.

3) My Machine is having 4GB RAM.

Do I need to increase any perm-size or heap size.. if so where can I ?

Can anybody please suggest me a workable solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Weblogic 11g does not support jdk1.8.

See: https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/weblogic_server_12_1_3